# How to list more than 1 output on prolog query?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

Imagine my siblings, my cousins and me and our total count is 10. So i write this code and when i run it, it just give me 1 output. How can i print all the X values(names) on this query. And if possible how can i change what name comes first or how can i choose as a like what 3rd or 5th name would be ? (My granduncle is my grandfather's brother.)

Here is my code and output

```
granduncle(T,X) :- brother(T,Z),parent(Z,Y),parent(Y,X).


?- granduncle(john,X).
X=stan
```

Comment: Do you want a list oft all solutions, or do you want to enumerate solutions one by one? For the latter, try pressing ";" or "Space" or "n" after each answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the collection predicates:

[`bagof/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3)
[`setof/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3)

and

[`findall/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)

to collect all the solutions into a single list.

For example:

```
bagof(X,granduncle(john,X),Bag).
```

will create a list of solutions in `Bag`.

Then you can slice & dice the list with predicates like:

- [`sort/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2)
- [`exclude/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=exclude/3)
- [`partition/4`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=partition/4)

Comment: And why not just `setof/3` in place of `bagof/3`?

Comment: @false It evidently depends on what you want to do. What if there are no duplicates? Then `bagof/3` - it will (probably) be faster by a couple of milliseconds (old habits grown on sub-10-MHz CPUs die hard)

Comment: As far as I remember SWI, its `setof/3` no longer depends on  `bagof/3` and thus can easily be of same speed. Also `setof/3` hides the often varying order - even if you do not have redundant solutions.